# Character replacing in Xcode - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, nsstring

I have used this code for replacing "\n" with "", but it is not working.

How can I do it?

```
NSString *descString = [values objectForKey:@"description"];
descString = [descString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"Description String ---->>> %@",descString);
catlog.description = descString;
[webview loadHTMLString:catlog.description baseURL:nil];
webview.opaque = NO;
```

Comment: for html sending and receiving use encoding and decoding of URl http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7088079/how-to-pass-an-string-value-in-url-in-iphone-app/10054500#10054500 please like it

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005281/remove-newline-character-from-first-line-of-nsstring

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: We don't have crystal balls. Telling us that it is not working without telling us *how* it is not working or what you have tried makes it hard to come up with a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
descString = [descString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@""];
```

For more information refer to [stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-SW6) method

Hope this helps you.

**UPDATE**

*Swift 3.0*

```
descString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: "");
```

and If I am not wring it will also work for *Swift 4.0*

Answer (score 10):

try this

```
NSString *s = @"foo/bar:baz.foo";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:."];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```